# Why does StreamBuilder uses initialData multiple times and not it's latest snapshot?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

I probably just misunderstand the dart's stream, but when I do this:

```
TabBarView(
  children: [
    ...
    StreamBuilder(
      builder(context, url){ 
        ...
        print(url);
        ...
      },
      stream: () async* { ... }().asBroadcastStream(),
      initialData: 'Dope',
    )
    ...
  ]
)
```

I get some strange behaviors when rendering the StreamBuilder using the TabBarView.

First, I have to use *asBroadcastStream()* otherwise I get a:

> Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

which I acknowledge is a bad solution.

But, while the solution works, going back to the StreamBuilder in the TabBarView will now rebuild reusing initialData and not the stream's latest snapshot. Here's the output of print when going back to the tab twice:

> I/flutter (14541): dope
>   I/flutter (14541): properURL
>   I/flutter (14541): dope
>   I/flutter (14541): dope

I image both issues are related, but I don't understand why StreamBuilder reuses the async* and initialData

Comment: Wrapping the StreamBuilder in a Builder fixes the second issue, no idea why tho..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your widget is being recreated, transform it into a `StatefulWidget` and override `dispose()` with a `print(disposed)` inside of it to confirm.

Also, inside the `StreamBuilder` print the `snapshot.connectionState`, your `connectionState` is probably changing to `waiting` to `active` and so the builder is being called with `initalData`.

This is what I can guess for the little of code you posted, test this out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: printing connectionState confirmed the stream was doing `waiting` -> `active` for first render and only `waiting` for further rendering

Comment: So if this answers your question don't forget to accept it and vote for it